# what are chains of transmitters of quran?

Tags: quran

i heard about chains of transmitters of quran. do they exist? how many chains are there? where can i read them? can we see in them that quran was also transmitted in chains in times when written quran was [collected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Quran) by abu bakr and uthman, separately from their written versions? are there cases of a person learned part of quran from one person and part from another person?

Comment: Please use your mind prior to asking such a question! The people who have compiled the qur'an at the time of abu Bakr or 'Uthman were the sahabah , they have derectly heard the qur'an from the prophet or from some of the known hufadh of the sahabah. As for today's hufadh each of them may share his own one. I strongly suggest you to overthink your first draft and rephrase your question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i do not understand. can you show exactly which sentence has what flaw. some chain may go through a hafiz who used written version of abu bakr or uthman (to help to remember), maybe they themselves (abu bakr or uthman) where hafizes, i do not know. some chain might go not going through them and like independently from their paper/material books.

Comment: You can't call a person hafidh who learnt qur'an from a book or papers. The qur'an is ever since only transmitted orally.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i think that, generally, if there are some misconceptions in question, it is ok, because it is natural that person who asks do not know something. answers may explain that things.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Please help me. Have all the Qur'an's qiraats always been mutawatir? I have heard that the reading of Hafs was ahad before he was declared one of the seven kiraats by Ibn Mujahid. Is it true?